# How to put gnerics when calling this method?

Tags: java, generics

I have some static method.

```
   public static <D extends BaseDoseDetail<I>, I extends BaseDoseInstance, P extends BasePrescribedPrescription<D, I>, M extends BaseMedicationTreatment<D, I, P>> List<P> getUnSignedPrescriptions(final M medicationTreatment)
  {

    return medicationTreatment.getPrescriptions().stream()
      .filter(input -> MedToolkit.INSTANCE.isUnsigned(input.getSigningStatus())).collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
```

I need to call it , like this.

```
 List unSignedPrescriptions = BaseDosageInfoUtil.getUnSignedPrescriptions(treatments);
```

but need help to put generics here. I need some expert help to resolve this ?

Comment: what's the type of `treatments`?

Comment: its type of `M`

Comment: what is wrong here, what is the error you got?

Comment: @subash `M` is a generic type parameter. I was asking what actual type the OP is passing for that argument?

Comment: @subash M extends BaseMedicationTreatment<D, I, P>  , and that interface this type public interface BaseMedicationTreatment<DD extends BaseDoseDetail<DI>, DI extends BaseDoseInstance, P extends BasePrescribedPrescription<DD, DI>>
{ }

Answer (score 1):

Based on the definition of your method, you should call it with types such as:

```
BaseMedicationTreatment<BaseDoseDetail<BaseDoseInstance>, BaseDoseInstance, BasePrescribedPrescription<BaseDoseDetail<BaseDoseInstance>,BaseDoseInstance>> treatments = ...;
List<BasePrescribedPrescription<BaseDoseDetail<BaseDoseInstance>,BaseDoseInstance>> unSignedPrescriptions = BaseDosageInfoUtil.getUnSignedPrescriptions(treatments);
```

Of course, any of these classes can be replaced with sub-classes, as long as they match the generic type bounds.

Comment: I put but not succsess